# Mono Android pinch zoom whilst overriding ondraw

Tags: android, zooming, pinch

I've ported some android code for zooming an imageview to mono for android, but I am having trouble with the scale detector focus point. I need to programmatically draw objects so I am overriding the ondraw method.

The problem is that when I have a zoom scale of anything other than 1, if I pinch on one side of the drawn object, the drawn object jumps away from pinch focus point and you end up with a focus point other than what you started with (if the zoom scale is greater than 1). If the zoom scale is less than 1, the drawn object jumps towards the pinch focus.

I've tried just about everything, but I must be getting too old and tired, because I just can't figure it out.

In the ondraw, I am scaling then translating, then drawing the object at a fixed point.

Am I going about this in the right manner? I cannot find anything on searches that involve drawing an object at a point on a canvas whilst implementing pinch zooming.

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Code is as follows...

```
class clsTarget : ImageView, ImageView.IOnTouchListener
{
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private ScaleListener sListener;
    private static float mScaleFactor = 0.6F;
    private static float scalePointX;
    private static float scalePointY;

    private static int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    private static float mPosX, mPosY, mLastTouchX, mLastTouchY;

    public clsTarget(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
        this.SetOnTouchListener(this);

        sListener = new ScaleListener();
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, sListener);
        mScaleFactor = 800F / (float)Math.Min(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels, Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels);
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.Save();

        canvas.Scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, scalePointX, scalePointY);
        canvas.Translate(mPosX, mPosY);

        Paint p = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
        p.Color = Color.Orange;
        p.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
        p.StrokeWidth = 1F;
        canvas.DrawCircle(400, 400, 200, p);

        canvas.Restore();
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        mScaleDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);

        switch (e.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                float x = (e.GetX() - scalePointX) / mScaleFactor;
                float y = (e.GetY() - scalePointY) / mScaleFactor;

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                mActivePointerId = e.GetPointerId(0);
                break;

            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                int pointerIndex = e.FindPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);

                float x2 = (e.GetX(pointerIndex) - scalePointX) / mScaleFactor;
                float y2 = (e.GetY(pointerIndex) - scalePointY) / mScaleFactor;

                float dx = (x2 - mLastTouchX);
                float dy = (y2 - mLastTouchY);

                if (!mScaleDetector.IsInProgress)
                {
                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;

                    mLastTouchX = x2;
                    mLastTouchY = y2;
                }

                this.Invalidate();

                break;

            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;

            case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;

            case MotionEventActions.PointerUp:
                int pointerIndex2 = (int)(e.Action & MotionEventActions.PointerIndexMask) >> (int)MotionEventActions.PointerIndexShift;
                int pointerID = e.GetPointerId(pointerIndex2);

                if (pointerID == mActivePointerId)
                {
                    int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;

                    mLastTouchX = (e.GetX(newPointerIndex) - scalePointX) / mScaleFactor;
                    mLastTouchY = (e.GetY(newPointerIndex) - scalePointY) / mScaleFactor;

                    mActivePointerId = e.GetPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }

                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
    {
        public override bool OnScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            scalePointX = detector.FocusX;
            scalePointY = detector.FocusY;

            mScaleFactor *= detector.ScaleFactor;
            mScaleFactor = Math.Max(0.5f, Math.Min(mScaleFactor, 7.0f));

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mind telling us what the problem was :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry,bad English.

First,Case MotionEventActions.Move,when ScaleDetector.IsInProgress is true, set mLastGestureX and mLastGesturey.

In the OnDraw,when ScaleDetector.IsInProgress is false, 
canvas.Scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,mLastGestureX,mLastGestureY)

Code is as follows...

```
class ImageViewExt : ImageView
{
    private static int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;
    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private float mLastGestureX;
    private float mLastGestureY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private static float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;

    public ImageViewExt(Context context):base(context)
    {
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(Context,new ScaleListener());
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent (MotionEvent e)
    {
        mScaleDetector.OnTouchEvent (e);

        //int action = e.Action;
        switch (e.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask) {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            if (!mScaleDetector.IsInProgress) {
                float x = e.GetX ();
                float y = e.GetY ();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = e.GetPointerId (0);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Pointer1Down:
            if (mScaleDetector.IsInProgress) {
                float gx = mScaleDetector.FocusX;
                float gy = mScaleDetector.FocusY;

                mLastGestureX = gx;
                mLastGestureY = gy;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            if (!mScaleDetector.IsInProgress) {
                int pointerIdx = e.FindPointerIndex (mActivePointerId);
                float x = e.GetX (pointerIdx);
                float y = e.GetY (pointerIdx);

                float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                Invalidate ();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
            } else {
                float gx = mScaleDetector.FocusX;
                float gy = mScaleDetector.FocusY;

                float gdx = gx - mLastGestureX;
                float gdy = gy - mLastGestureY;

                mPosX += gdx;
                mPosY += gdy;

                Invalidate ();

                mLastGestureX = gx;
                mLastGestureY = gy;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.PointerUp:

            int pointerIdx2 = (int)(e.Action & MotionEventActions.PointerIndexMask) >> (int)MotionEventActions.PointerIndexShift;
            int pointerId = e.GetPointerId (pointerIdx2);

            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                int NewPointerIndex = pointerIdx2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = e.GetX (NewPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = e.GetY (NewPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = e.GetPointerId (NewPointerIndex);
            }
            else{
                int TempPointerIdx = e.FindPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                mLastTouchX = e.GetX(TempPointerIdx);
                mLastTouchY = e.GetY(TempPointerIdx);
            }
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected override void OnDraw (Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.Save ();

        canvas.Translate (mPosX, mPosY);
        if (mScaleDetector.IsInProgress) {
            canvas.Scale (mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleDetector.FocusX, mScaleDetector.FocusY);
        } else {
            canvas.Scale (mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,mLastGestureX,mLastGestureY);
        }
        base.OnDraw (canvas);
        canvas.Restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
    {
        public override bool OnScale (ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.ScaleFactor;

            //小さすぎず大きすぎず処理
            mScaleFactor = Math.Max(0.1f, Math.Min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

            return true;
        }

    }
}
```